# How to let sensors periodically work?

Tags: android

I am currently developing an app in Android which will record sensor data for a fixed length of time for several cycles. For example, I plan to record the data for 10 seconds, and then stop, let the phone rest for 10 seconds, and start record again, ... working in this pattern for 1 hour. My question is, how to let the phone automatically execute this plan?  I am currently using code below ( from [Android: How to collect sensor values for a fixed period of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119297/android-how-to-collect-sensor-values-for-a-fixed-period-of-time)) , but it only works for one cycle, I have to manually start new cycles after I am sure the previous cycle has finished.

```
public void onResume() {
mSensorManager.registerListener(mListener, mSensorAcceleration, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
mSensorManager.registerListener(mListener, mSensorMagnetic, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    //    do stuff with sensor values
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mListener);               
    }
}, 10000);
```

...

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Have your activity implement `Runnable`, rather than use an anonymous inner class, moving your `run()` method to be implemented on the activity.

Step #2: In your `run()` method, schedule yourself (the activity) to run again after a delay using `postDelayed()`. This, plus your existing call to `postDelayed()`, will effectively set up a periodic call to `run()`.

Step #3: Keep track of whether you are in "sensors on" or "sensors off" mode, and, in `run()`, either register or unregister the listeners as appropriate.

Step #4: In `onPause()`, call `removeCallbacks()` on your `Handler` to stop the periodic calls to `run()`.

You will see an example of this sort of schedule-yourself-to-run-again logic in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Threads/PostDelayed). Here is the activity:

```
package com.commonsware.android.post;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PostDelayedDemo extends Activity implements Runnable {
  private static final int PERIOD=5000;
  private View root=null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    root=findViewById(android.R.id.content);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    run();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    root.removeCallbacks(this);

    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(PostDelayedDemo.this, "Who-hoo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
         .show();
    root.postDelayed(this, PERIOD);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a better and more correct way to implement this. Specifically, I think it's wrong to let the `Activity` implement `Runnable`. It leaks logic in its public interface that should be kept private (and hidden). I.e. no one is ever supposed to invoke `run()` outside the activity. I would suggest implementing it as follows instead:

```
public class PostDelayedDemo extends Activity {
  // Declaration of sensor-related fields.

  private static final int PERIOD = 10000;
  private Handler handler;
  private final Runnable processSensors =
      new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
           mSensorManager.registerListener(mListener, mSensorAcceleration, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
           mSensorManager.registerListener(mListener, mSensorMagnetic, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

           // Do work with the sensor values.

           mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mListener);

           // The Runnable is posted to run again here:
           handler.postDelayed(this, PERIOD);
         }
      };

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    handler = new Handler();
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    handler.post(processSensors);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(processSensors);

    super.onPause();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is cleaner. Rather than make the whole activity as a runnable object, we make a runnable instance variable.