# How to read pressure sensor every x minutes?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-sensors

I have this function in my barometer service:

```
  public void StartHpsUpdates()
    {
        var x = (SensorDelay)125000000;
        var d = 125000000;
        sm.RegisterListener(this, _pressure, x, d);
    }
```

that should read sensor data every 125 seconds.

I also have event handler

```
    public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
    {
        this.SensorChanged(this, new SensorChangedEventArgs(e));
        var hps = e.Values[0];
        Log.Debug(logTag, String.Format("Hps is {0}",  hps));
    }
```

which is printing data to console, for test purposes. But, instead of a single data reading every 2 minutes, in console i'm getting hundreds of readings at once every 30-40 seconds, something like this

```
11-15 11:09:09.501 D/LocationService(25609): Hps is 1002,648
11-15 11:09:09.511 D/LocationService(25609): Hps is 1002,653
11-15 11:09:09.531 D/LocationService(25609): Hps is 1002,66
11-15 11:09:09.541 D/LocationService(25609): Hps is 1002,667
11-15 11:09:09.551 D/LocationService(25609): Hps is 1002,67
11-15 11:09:09.551 D/LocationService(25609): Hps is 1002,676
11-15 11:09:09.561 D/LocationService(25609): Hps is 1002,677
11-15 11:09:09.571 D/LocationService(25609): Hps is 1002,674
```

I have tried to find solution, but no luck so far, looks like no one is using pressure sensor. Can someone point me how to do this?

Comment: what is **logTag**? where's the part where you insert the timestamp into the log?

Comment: logTag is string, and timestamp is inserted in Log.Debug()...

Comment: SensorDelay is an enumeration, not an integer, so I guess you're just assigning it a value that is not valid and the framework interprets it as some "default" one. Does the rate change if you use different values SensorDelay.Fastest, SensorDelay.Game, SensorDelay.Normal, SensorDelay.Ui from the enumeration?

Comment: Documentation says, it can be integer after API v19.

Comment: Have a read of this 'old' post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829972/how-to-set-delay-of-android-sensors-programmatically